# Dropdown list like Spinner in Android

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-spinner

I am trying to implement a dropdown list that looks like the web drop down list.. But what i could implement was only the spinner which can select an item but it doesn't give the idea of drop down..anyone who knows a work around it?..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess that would be possible with inflating a custom view to your layout onClicking the spinner/button(faked spinner)

Comment: Yeah..Thats worth a try..I'll give a try...Thanks

Comment: Spinners support both a 'dropdown' and 'dialog' mode. From the sounds of it, you're looking for the former. To what extend does that not give you the result you are after?

Answer (score 1):

Web like drop down means, do you think about like lable on top "Select Value" and below a list of values ?

If yes then you can do it by creating a custom Spinner. Just create a lable, on click of it open a Dialog and bind list values to the dialog. So it will behave completely same as Spinner.

Hope it helps

Comment: Actually what i have been looking for is to implement a drop down list which looks same as the web drop down list.. Not a spinner.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dummy button similar like dropdown. Just below it use invisible/gone scrollview. Inside scrollview use listview.   On click, make it visible.